# A question about cross product of C*-dynamical system

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Here is a Theorem (P123) in a book "C*-algebras and Finite-Dimensional Approximations" by N.P.Brown and N. Ozawa.

> **Theorem 4.2.4.** Let $A$ be a C*-algebra and $\mathbb{Z}$ be the set of integers. For an automophism $\alpha\in Aut(A)$, the following statements are true:
>
> (1) $A\rtimes_{\alpha} \mathbb{Z}=A\rtimes_{\alpha, r}\mathbb{Z}$.
>
> (2) ....
>
> **Proof.** Proof of (1): It suffices to show that there exsit c.c.p. (contractive completely positive) maps
>   $$\Psi_{n}:A\rtimes_{\alpha,r}\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow A\rtimes_{\alpha}\mathbb{Z}$$
>   such that $||x-\Psi_{n}\circ\pi(x)||_{u}\rightarrow0$ for all $x\in C_{c}(\mathbb{Z}, A)\subset A\rtimes_{\alpha} \mathbb{Z}$, where 
>   $$\pi:A\rtimes_{\alpha}\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow A\rtimes_{\alpha,r}\mathbb{Z}$$
>   is the canonical quotient map(coming from universality).
>
> .....

**My question is**, in order to prove the isomorphism
, why does the author find such a c.c.p map $\Psi_{n}$.

In the Theorem, the $A\rtimes_{\alpha}\Gamma$ denotes the *full crossed product* of a C*-dynamical system $(A, \alpha, \Gamma)$, which is the completion of $C_{c}(\Gamma, A)$ with respect to the norm $$||x||_{u}=sup||\pi(x)||,$$
where the supremum is over all (cyclic) *-homomorphisms $\pi:C_{c}(\Gamma, A)\rightarrow B(H)$. While the $A\rtimes_{\alpha,r}\Gamma$ denotes the *reduced crossed product* of a C*-dynamical system $(A, \alpha, \Gamma)$, which is the norm closure of the image of a regular representation $C_{c}(\Gamma, A)\rightarrow B(H\otimes l^{2}(\Gamma))$. In addition, the $C_{c}(\Gamma, A)$ denotes the linear space of finitely supported functions on $\Gamma$ with values in $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is simply this fact: take $x\in\ker\pi$. From the relation in the first paragraph of the proof, 
$$
x=\lim_n\Psi_n(\pi(x))=\lim_n\Psi(0)=0.
$$
So $\pi$ is an isometric epimorphism, and so an isomorphism.